# how to stream a local file to red5 1.0 server using latest red5 client

Tags: client, red5, rtmp

I've tried many samples, the only one which works is from 
https://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/source/browse/trunk/example/com/ryong21/example/publisher/PublishClient.java

But it doesn't compatible with latest server side code.
This sample use a org.red5.server.stream.provider.FileProvider to read a local video file whose constructor has changed from FileProvider(File file) to FileProvider(IScope scope,File file). I'm not quite sure how to make the scope argument, neither null nor "new GlobalScope"  works.

And another issue, even with the working example, it only works with red5 server but not with
youtube rtmp server. Any ideas?

Edit:
I finally get it worked by making scope like this
http://pastebin.com/jnwv1ewd

But it still doesn't work with youtube, the error msg is 
"1418  INFO  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Processing server response for encryption
1420  WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandshake - Type 0 digest comparison failed, trying type 1 algorithm"

Handshake failed?

Answer (score 0):

That message means that one of the two handshake validation routines failed; not that the whole thing failed. YouTube RTMP has special requirements and you must meet or exceed a given number of subscribers before you are allowed to access it.